# How to pass a query parameter without displaying it in the browser

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new in BackboneJs and I need some help to pass parameters in URL using GET with Jersey.

In fact, I have table of documents like the following :

[image: Document table]

When I click on a PDF picto, it opens the PDF document using the `documentID`.

**Front side (BackboneJs)**

```
getDatas: function(e){
    var clickedEl = $(e.currentTarget);
    var id = clickedEl.attr("id");
    window.open(window.myApp.baseUrlService.defaultUrl + '/getDocument.json?an200_idDocument=' + id);
},
```

So here I get the `documentId` and I use it in the backend to open the document.

**Back side (JAVA)**

```
@GET
@Path("/getDocument.json")
public Response getDocumentById(@QueryParam("an200_idDocument") String idDocument){
 // my code here
}
```

It works perfectly but my problem is when I open the document, I can see the `documentId` which is not secure. I tried with `@POST` but it didn't work.

[image: URL with document ID]

So, there is any other solution ?

Comment: What "didn't work" about the `@POST`?

Comment: @peeskillet  i can pass the id but when i open the document i get `javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: When you say "open document",. you mean you just type the URL in the browser? If so, of course it won't work. The default method for the browser URL bar is a GET (hence "Method Not Allowed"). You need to make the POST request from your Javascript; And XHR (AJAX) request). If you wan't you could also redirect from the POST endpoint to abouther GET endpoint. Not sure exactly what you're trying to do. You could also make a GET request and set the ID in the header, if that would be more secure for you.

Comment: Indeed i did it, it looks just obvious to say it. and in console i get binary data of the pdf in red.

Comment: Trying to hide the ID is pointless from a security standpoint since it's already available to the user. Everything in the frontend (Backbone app) should be considered insecure data.

Comment: @EmileBergeron If you could give me an example to do this i'll appreciate it :)

Comment: My point is to **not do this** as it's useless. It's security by obscurity and it isn't secure by definition.

Comment: @EmileBergeron So do you have any other proposition? Thanks
What i think as a solution is to use GET and send encrypted id to the server wich contains a function do decrypt it. Is that doable?

Comment: If the `document_id` is sensitive, do not send it to the frontend, at all. Think of some other way for the frontend to identify a document, like short live tokens, slugs, etc.

Comment: There's no point to encrypt data in the browser as it would be already compromised.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I have to send the id cause i'll use it to get the document's binary data. Thank you any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Anything in the browser should be considered compromised already.**

Any encryption in JS is pointless since the data is already available to the malicious party.

## So how to hide the document id?

### The data is not sensitive

Generally, ids are not sensitive information. Since you're already sending them to the frontend for the user to be able to ask for a specific document, they're already easily available.

Consider not worrying about these ids.

### Use GUID

If the ids are currently a guessable sequence (1, 2, 3, etc.) and the user is not logged in meaning that the URL is publicly accessible, consider storing a GUID in the database for each document and use it to identify them.

```
/getDocument.json?an200_idDocument=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

It's far less likely for someone to guess a GUID.

Make these chances close to none by namespacing with a category for example, or a user ID if the user is logged in the app.

```
/getDocument.json?cat=bills&an200_idDocument=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

### Check the permissions by object

If the user is logged in, check if he has access to the document from the backend before returning a response. If he does not have access, return a *403 Forbidden* response.

### Use short-lived tokens

If the document should be accessible only once for a user, consider short-lived tokens which are unique strings associated to the user or the document and they expires after X amount of times or after X document requests.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's more obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's no possibility to completely hide the parameters of an URL using GET, that is in fact one of the main point between GET and POST. Unless you encrypt those datas in order to hide them using GET or use a POST method, you'll have no other solution.

More details between them there : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Thank you, indeed and when i tried @POST it didn't work. i'll try to encrypt  the Id.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look here, if you do not need a high-level encryption : [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13). Easily doable in JavaScript.